# Calculate percent change across rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this has been asked before but none of the answers made any sense to me. Hoping someone can explain more clearly.

My data:

```
year    quarter month   item    sales   quantity    month_number
2011        1   January    a    4250    85000       1
2011        1   February   a    4600    92000       2
2011        1   March      a    3700    74000       3
2011        2   April      a    4215    84300       4
2011        2   May        a    5120    102400      5
2011        2   June       a    5010    100200      6
2011        3   July       a    4690    93800       7
2011        3   August     a    4900    98000       8
2011        3   September  a    5400    108000      9
2011        4   October    a    5820    116400      10
2011        4   November   a    5900    118000      11
2011        4   December   a    5730    114600      12
2011        1   January    b    1417    35417       1
2011        1   February   b    1533    38333       2
2011        1   March      b    1233    30833       3
2011        2   April      b    1405    35125       4
2011        2   May        b    1707    42667       5
2011        2   June       b    1670    41750       6
2011        3   July       b    1563    39083       7
2011        3   August     b    1633    40833       8
2011        3   September  b    1800    45000       9
2011        4   October    b    1940    48500       10
2011        4   November   b    1967    49167       11
2011        4   December   b    1910    47750       12
```

I'm trying to create a new column at the end that contains the percent change for sales from month to month for each item (a & b). So, both month_number 1s would be a null value because there would be no change. But month_number 2 should be equal to (4600 - 4250)/4250, which is 0.082.
And so on.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quarter is redundant, right? (As is month)

Comment: which rdbms?  sql-server you can use LAG.  And you can also do it with self join

Comment: If you have code you want explained, you have to provide the code.

Comment: Yes, it's just in the data. Not needed for this particular problem I do not think.

Comment: Not sure, Matt. I'm brand new to sql. I have tried LAD but it is not a function in my version. I have been trying with a self join, but just do not know enough about to SQL to do it correctly.

Comment: Scott, I could provide a couple of words from a SELECT statement, but have no idea how to approach this so I'm afraid I do not have code to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.*
    ,CASE
       WHEN t2.sales IS NULL THEN NULL
       ELSE (t1.sales - t2.sales) / (t2.sales * 1.00)
    END AS MonthOverMonth
FROM
    #TblName t1
    LEFT JOIN #TblName t2
    ON t1.[Year] = t2.[Year]
    AND t1.month_number - 1 = t2.month_number
    AND t1.item = t2.item
```

Gordon has the LAG answer the way I was thinking to, but I was writing the non window function version in case you said mysql of something.  Anyway, LAG answer which is in SQL 2012 + .  `SELECT @@VERSION` should tell you which MSSQL version you are using.  But even without it you can just do a self join to the preceding month and do your calculation.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! Been googling for hours and could not find anything useful.

Comment: your welcome.  before all of the great window functions came about self joins where one good way to get to the types of comparisons

Answer (score 3):

You have not tagged your question with a database, so this answers in terms of ANSI standard functionality.  Most databases support `lag()`:

```
select d.*, (sales - prev_sales) / (prev_sales * 1.0)
from (select d.*
             lag(sales) over (partition by item order by year, month) as prev_sales
      from mydata md
     ) d;
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks. I am using Microsoft SQL Server (if that answers your question). I have tried lag() and it is not supported.

Comment: @MattCollins . . . SQL Server has supported `lag()` since 2012.

Comment: @MattCollins . . . I don't want to leave the impression for anyone reading the comments that SQL Server does not support `lag()`, because it does.